# Visual Studio SDK Breakpoint2.BreakWhenHit = true throws exception 0x8971101A

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, com-interop, visual-studio-sdk

The following code produces an exception:

```
Breakpoint2 breakpoint = ...;
breakpoint.BreakWhenHit = true;

// System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8971101A): Exception from HRESULT: 0x8971101A
//   at EnvDTE80.Breakpoint2.set_BreakWhenHit(Boolean BreakWhenHit)
```

However if I set `BreakWhenHit` to `false`, there is no exception.

Why does it happen and how do I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the operation fails if there is no `Message` set on breakpoint.
It's weird that it fails on `BreakWhenHit = true` (breakpoint), but in UI only tracepoints require a message.

Here is my workaround (sets/resets message when required):

```
private void SetBreakWhenHit(Breakpoint2 breakpoint, bool value) {
    var messageStubbed = false;
    if (value && string.IsNullOrEmpty(breakpoint.Message)) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753513/visual-studio-sdk-breakpoint2-breakwhenhit-true-throws-exception-0x8971101a
        breakpoint.Message = "stub";
        messageStubbed = true;
    }
    breakpoint.BreakWhenHit = value;
    if (messageStubbed)
        breakpoint.Message = "";
}
```